# Optional long parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type

Tags: java, spring

i have an ajax function which calling to a controller function but it not entered the controller. I'm getting the exception above in the controller function..

I changed instead of `long` as `Long`. But id value getting `null`. 
My **ajax url**

```
var url ="/portal/userUpdate?id="+id+"&uName="+uName+"&userUid="+userUid+"&userconctactno="+userconctactno;
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userUpdate")
        public @ResponseBody StatusResponse userList(@RequestParam(required = false) long id,@RequestParam(required = false) String uName,
                @RequestParam(required = false) String userUid,@RequestParam(required = false) String userconctactno, Model model)
                throws ParseException, SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException {
            System.out.println("--userUpdation--");
            //Mode code here


}
```

it does not print the system.out.println message.

exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional long parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.handleNullValue(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:98) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Comment: You could declare the id as `Long` instead of `long`, so it can be set to null.

Comment: ... which is exactly what the exception is telling you to do, helpfully. Did you *try* following the instructions in the exceptions?

Comment: Do you still get the same exception when running your code with Long instead of long ?

Comment: Still it looks like this  long id,@RequestParam(required = false)